# Solving Non Linear System of Equations with MATLAB

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, nonlinear-system

I encountered a non-linear system of equations that has to be solved.
The system of equations can be written as:
$$Ax + \exp(x) = b$$
with $b$ a known $N\times 1$ matrix, $A$ a known $N\times N$ matrix, and $x$ the unknown $N\times 1$ vector for which has to be solved. The $\exp$ is defined elementwise on the $x$ vector. I tried to search the Matlab-manual but I'm having a hard time finding how to solve this kind of equations with Matlab, so I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Maybe you could ask this question at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I changed $N\text{x}N$ to $N\times N$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923520/solving-non-linear-system-of-equations-in-matlab

Comment: I posted it on stackoverflow, on advise of thanasissdr :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be written in the form:

$$ f \left( x \right) = A x + \exp \left( x \right) - b $$

Which is equivalent to the above once a root of $ f \left( x \right) $ is found.
One could use [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for root finding.

The [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) (Like the Transpose of Gradient) of $ f \left( x \right) $ is given by:

$$ J \left( f \left( x \right) \right) = A + diag \left( \exp \left( x \right) \right) $$

Hence the newton iteration is given by:

$$ {x}^{k + 1} = {x}^{k} - { J \left( f \left( {x}^{k} \right) \right) }^{-1} f \left( {x}^{k} \right) $$

You can see the code in my [Mathematics Q1462386 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q1462386) which includes both analytic and numerical derivation of the Jacobian.

This is the result of one run:

[image]

Pay attention that while it finds a root for this problem there are more than 1 root hence the solution is one of many and depends on the initial point.